# Logic Apps Azure Save File Dialogue to OneDrive

Tags: html, azure-logic-apps

I have a super simple workflow and am embarrassed at not being able to figure this out.

1. Login to Site
2. Navigate to Report Download URL
3. Save the file (xlsx) to One Drive

I'm using two HTML tasks, the first to login and the second to get the file. (I've also used a OneDrive upload from URL in place of the second HTML task) Both save the 'body' of the HTML GET URL. I get a file of HTML.

There is an answer here describing use of a create blob, but I need to create an Azure resource for this. I suspect the answer is in the 'Body' text box where the hint is 'Enter Request Content'

[what is the content type for a 'save as or open' dialogue one sees in a browser when downloading a file?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QHrM.png)

I hope this is clear. I am so good at writing questions which make sense to me which go unanswered! I even appreciate constructive criticism in how I present the question!

[image]

Comment: Hi John, could you please provide one or more screenshots to show the whole of your logic app and point out which step you are concern about. Then I will try to help you solve the problem in that part of your logic app.

Comment: Thanks Hury, I appreciate the help. Other threads suggest a function must be written. Which is fine. The first HTTP task logs in. It does not fail but I'm not sure how to verify it works either. The second HTTP task contains the URL of the file one I navigate to the report and click download. Thank you for asking for clarification.

Comment: Hi John. As far as I know, it is difficult for us to do that just by logic app http connector. First, in your logic app, although the first http action login successfully, but the second http action should fail because it doesn't have authentication for the site. I think it is better to create a function to access the xlsx data from the url directly, but you have to write function code instead of just create some actions in logic app.

Comment: Thank you for returning the info as you said you would. I appreciate this so much. Let me understand. The second HTTP does not enjoy the authentication achieved by the first task? That is good to know. I am learning.

Comment: You suggest to remove both HTTP tasks and write a function? So my logic app will have a timer and a function.  That is it? I suppose I can just do this with python and selenium if I have to write code. Which I don't mind.

Comment: Yes, you can develop it with python and selenium. It is a good solution. But in logic app, as it doesn't have a connector for your download source, so it is not easy for us to download it by just create some actions. Or if you still want to use logic app to save the file to One drive, you can create a azure function with python and selenium code in it and call it in logic app. I will provide a solution about how to call this azure function in logic app and then save to One drive(in logic app).

Comment: Hi John, any update about this post ? Do you still want to use logic app to implement the requirement(call a azure function in logic app) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements from the question and the comments, I provide a solution(which use azure function and logic app) here for your reference:

First, you need to create a [azure function (python)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) and you can write the python code to download the xlsx file from the website. And then you can use [python sdk for azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage#upload-a-file) to upload the xlsx file to azure file storage.

Now, you have completed the development of your azure function. Then we need to call this azure function in logic app. Please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) to add the function you developed to your logic app.

Then we can use "[Get file content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/#get-file-content)" action from "Azure file storage" connector in logic app to get the xlsx file which we uploaded it to azure file storage.

At last, we need to use "[Create file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveconnector/#create-file)" action from "OneDrive" connector in logic app to save the file from the previous action("Get file content" from azure file storage) to One Drive.

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: I am happy with this answer and looks like the way I may go. The only problem is that the only python I can create requires Selenium. This does not work in Azure function in logic apps. So my solution is an Azure VM.